# What is the supply current in LM339N

Tags: voltage, operational-amplifier, current, supervisor

I am repairing a voltage protector that contains a LM339N, that working like comparator, in the datasheet say that the current consumption is the 0.8 mA (max 2 mA). I measured with a tester the current, with a power supply of 24V and I obtained a reading the 98 mA.
I don't understand, the LM339N is wrong? Or by to did these test I damaged it?
This is the circuit diagram, is a voltage protector of refrigeration, 120 VAC.

I desoldered the LM339N and measured the current with the dispositive outside of the PCB.

In the first instance, I am fixing a voltage protector that when it start to normal operation and it connect the relay, it started to oscillate the relay. Then I am looking for the damage, I removed the relay I realized that it had the contacts stuck, but that was as if it was bridged. I measured the Zeners and they are fine. I don't know what else I could do?

[image]

Comment: There will be a shunt zener in this cap supply circuit .Are you sure that the comparitor is taking all this 98mA .It would be dead and very hot .

Comment: If the opamp oscillates, it consumes much more current that quiescent current.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> with a power supply of 24V, I obtained a reading the 98 mA

The [1N4474A](https://www.nexperia.com/products/diodes/zener-diodes/1N4744A.html) is a 15V zener, and as wired, is supplied 24V through 220Ω R17.  24V-15V=9V, 9V/220Ω = 40.9mA.  This is where the bulk of your missing current is going.

Plus 2mA for each comparator, plus LEDs and other components = 98mA.

[image: Missing Current]

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, i understanded by where the flow current.

For solutions this problem i changed C2 and i put a zener diode in parallel to C2 and it started working.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for expanding your answer to explain the solution to your original question. Since you don't need further help then, as explained in [this article](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/353974), please click the "tick mark" ("check mark") to change it to a green color, to mark the question as solved / closed. Thanks.